# Monero project visual c++

Tags: build, c++

I want to edit c++ monero project in visual studio c++. Is anybody know where I can find this type of project? What kind of libraries are required?

Comment: Can you please re-phrase your question? It is super unclear what you are asking. Are you looking for the Monero source code? Trying to open the source code in Visual Studio? Something else?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for visual studio c++ monero project, and a list of all required libraries like sodium, boost etc.

Answer (score 3):

The Monero code is built using gcc. There is no support for building with Microsoft's tools, and it is not expected to work.

Answer (score 0):

Monero is an open-source project

You can find the current github for the project in the link below

https://github.com/monero-project/monero

Comment: Yes, I've these sources but problem is that I can't compile them because of missing libraries like sodium lib for example

Comment: Go to the github, on the first page, go to compiling from source, and underneath are the libraries required.